# Grails generate userguide

Tags: grails, documentation

I am trying to add documentation to my Grails 4.0.4 application. I am using the grails-doc plugin. I can generate API documents just fine, but how do I generate the guide.

I am trying to follow the following instructions.

http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/docs.html
https://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/guide/conf.html#docengine

Jeff Brown gave me ideas, so I built an example app using some of the logic from the grails-cache-master project. I have it almost there. It seems like I might have a version conflict somewhere. Here is my error.

| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not find method grailsPublish() for arguments [build_1jdtxosno0reefmsskx10gzij$_run_closure9@6c0f10e9] on root project 'DocExample' of type org.gradle.api.Project. (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)

Here is my sample project.
https://www.dropbox.com/t/Ipk0etkD2i7BqzjI

Thanks
Larry